# Calculate $\int_0^7\sin\left(\frac{2\pi\cdot 3x}{5}\right)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi\cdot 15 \operatorname{frac}(x)}{8}\right)dx$

Tags: integration, closed-form, periodic-functions, fractional-part

After I was playing with the formulas $\cos(a\pm b)$ and [1], I wondered a different case from those calculations that I was doing in the context to study  the formula of [1].

> **Question.** Let $\operatorname{frac}(x)= \left\{ x \right\}$ the fractional part function. Is it possible calculate a closed-form for $$\int_0^7\sin\left(\frac{2\pi\cdot 3x}{5}\right)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi\cdot 15 \left\{ x \right\}}{8}\right)dx\,?\tag{I}$$ Then, please provide me a way to get it. **Many thanks.**

I presume that using [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com), and my knowledges (the fractional part is periodic) that I can to prove closed-forms for different integrals but more simple than previous. Wolfram Alpha online calculator (using standard time of computation), provide me the output

`int sin(2 pi 3 x/5)sin(2 pi 15 frac(x)/8)dx, from x=0 to 7`

Now as comparison look at from this different input, the closed-form that  Wolfram Alpha provide me

`int sin(2 pi 3 x/5)sin(2 pi 15 frac(x)/5)dx, from x=0 to 7`

That I am asking this: is if we can get a closed-form for the integral (I), and how do it.

### References:

[1] George Purdy, *An Integral Equal to* $\sigma(n)$, Problems and Solutions, Problem E 1850 [1966, 82], The American Mathematical MONTHLY, Vol. 74 N. 5, p. 594-595 (MAY, 1967).

Comment: Hint: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Comment: You can break the integral into 7 parts, in each part the `frac(x)` expression can be represented without `frac`.

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution, I am more contributions, because notice that by the plot of Wolfram Alpha, the calculation of the integral (I) seems very complicated @labbhattacharjee

Comment: But each "slice" (range such that `frac(x)` is continuous) is pretty simple.

Comment: Many thanks @user202729 , I am asking because I don't know if the only strategy,is that you're saying that is decompose the interval of integration and using that the fractional part function is periodic and calculate all those complicated calculations with a CAS.

Comment: There may be simpler way, but that means it is possible to calculate a closed form. The question doesn't explicitly say that you should find it, just that you should determine if there exists a closed-form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a general roadmap.

First, one may show that, for continuous and integrable functions $f$ and $g$:

$$\int_0^N dx \, f(x) g(\{x\}) = \int_0^1 dx \, g(x) \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} f(x+k)$$

where $N \in \mathbb{N}$.  For your integral, the sum boils down to

$$\sum_{k=0}^7 \sin{\left ( \frac{6 \pi}{5} (x+k) \right )} = A \cos{\left ( \frac{6 \pi}{5} x \right )} + B \sin{\left ( \frac{6 \pi}{5} x \right )}$$

where $A$ and $B$ are, respectively, imaginary and real parts of the quantity $1/(e^{-i 2 \pi/5}+1)$.  This then reduces to two integrals:

$$\int_0^1 dx \, \sin{\left ( \frac{15 \pi}{4} x \right )} \cos{\left ( \frac{6 \pi}{5} x \right )} $$

$$\int_0^1 dx \, \sin{\left ( \frac{15 \pi}{4} x \right )} \sin{\left ( \frac{6 \pi}{5} x \right )} $$

which I assume you can do.

Comment: Perfect, many thanks. I am going to read and study your answer.